# how pipe() will performing read and write operations in node js?

Tags: stream, pipe, chain, node.js-stream

```
var fs = require("fs");

var readStream= fs.createReadStream('input.txt');

var writeStream=fs.createWriteStream('output.txt');

readStream.pipe(writeStream);

console.log("hello...world");
```

In the above program, `readStream` and `writeStream` operations are done by pipe function..what was the internal code and internal process happening in the `pipe()`?

Answer (score 0):

piping will performs like a bridge in nodejs.
review here: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_pipe